# NSString memory issue while creating JSONString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my app, i have a function to create a JSONString by using NSJSONSerialization. This function is called multiple times in few seconds to generate long JSONString. This NSString is causing memory issue which results in app crash.

```
-(NSString *)getJSONString:(NSArray *)arrayWithDictionary{
      NSError *error =nil;
      NSString *jsonStringToReturn = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayWithDictionary options:0 error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      return jsonStringToReturn;
}
```

arrayWithDictionary has many NSDictionary into it. I have placed the code inside @autoreleasepool to avoid memory issue, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What sort of "memory issue"?

Comment: In Allocations Instrument, it is shown that the string has used up to 600 MB memory.

Comment: You'll need to show how are you using that method as there is nothing wrong with it, in itself.

Comment: Why are you creating a string? There is nothing useful that you can do with that string.

Comment: it is a scenario only. The string created, is send back to js as a pluginResult.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a dictionary with JSON data to a string takes memory. The way to get round this is simple: Don't do it. First, there is no reason why you would need a string. Convert JSON to NSData and leave it like that. Second, you can convert the JSON data not to NSData, but to a file. No memory needed at all.

Third, make sure that you don't have data that isn't needed anymore in some autorelease pool.